# How to parse login response in android?

Tags: java, android, json, api

I am confused about parsing so I want to know about how to parse. Whenever I login with valid login id and password give response

```
{
  "data": {
    "status": "1",
    "Full Name": [
      {
        "user_id": 1,
        "user_name": "deepika@soms.in",
        "full_name": "",
        "display_name": "",
        "token": "",
        "photo_url": "http://clients.vfactor.in/putt2gether/images/profile/default.jpg"
      }
    ],
    "Event": [
      {
        "latest_event_id": "",
        "format_id": ""
      }
    ],
    "msg": "Success Login"
  }
}
```

and if invalid login id then give response

```
{
  "Error": {
    "msg": "Please Enter valid Email Address"
  }
```

Comment: Parsing JSON is confusing at first, but have you at the very least tried? Do you have any codes that you've used?

Comment: This is a JSON format response ..you should parse the JSON response by libraries like Volley  https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Comment: i have parse very well but how to parse error section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
     JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
            if (obj.has("Error")) {
                JSONObject objError = obj.getJSONObject("Error");
            } else if (obj.has("data")) {
                JSONObject objData = obj.getJSONObject("data");
            }
    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Chirag Arora

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the json answer.

There are many sources to learn how to do that:

- [Oracle documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html)
- [Jackson documentation](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes) - Jackson is a library to parse json
- [GSon documentation](https://github.com/google/gson) - Another json parser

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume response be,

String response;

```
try 
  {
   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

   if (jsonObject.has("data")) 
     {
            JSONObject jsonObjData = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");

            String status = jsonObject.getString("status");

            JSONArray jsonArrayName = jsonObjData.getJSONArray("Full Name");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayName.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArrayName.getJSONObject(i);

                Integer user_id = jsonObj.getInt("user_id");
                String user_name = jsonObj.getString("user_name");
                String full_name = jsonObj.getString("full_name");
                String display_name = jsonObj.getString("display_name");
                String photo_url = jsonObj.getString("photo_url");
            }

            JSONArray jsonArrayEvent = jsonObjData.getJSONArray("Event");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayEvent.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArrayEvent.getJSONObject(i);

                String latest_event_id = jsonObj.getString("latest_event_id");
                String format_id = jsonObj.getString("format_id");
            }

            String msg = jsonObject.getString("msg");
        } else if (jsonObject.has("Error")) {
            JSONObject jsonObjError = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Error");

            String msg = jsonObjError.getString("msg");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```